# Access xml element by index number in for loop

Tags: c#, xml

How can I loop through each element so instead of repeating element names I can access by index number.

I have foreach loop to get each attribute value but in the loop I repeat times. 
inside foreachloop I added for loop and after finding number of total element (totalAttItem ). I want to use this to access each element by index.

I tried this but not worked.

```
string lienName = lien.Element[i].Element("name").Value;
```

**code**

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
foreach (var lien in doc.Descendants("LIEN_CLAIMANT"))
{
    int totalAttItem = lien.Elements().Count();

    for (int i = 0; i < totalAttItem; i++)
    {
        string lienName = lien.Element("item0").Element("name").Value;
        string lienRole = lien.Element("item0").Element("role").Value;
        string lienAddress = lien.Element("item0").Element("address").Value;
        string lienStreet = lien.Element("item0").Element("street").Value;
        string lienCity = lien.Element("item0").Element("city").Value;  

        string lienName1 = lien.Element("item1").Element("name").Value;
        string lienRole1 = lien.Element("item1").Element("role").Value;
        string lienAddress1 = lien.Element("item1").Element("address").Value;
        string lienStreet = lien.Element("item1").Element("street").Value;
        string lienCity1 = lien.Element("item1").Element("city").Value;   

        string lienName2 = lien.Element("item2").Element("name").Value;
        string lienRole2 = lien.Element("item2").Element("role").Value;
        string lienAddress2 = lien.Element("item2").Element("address").Value;
        string lienStreet2 = lien.Element("item2").Element("street").Value;
        string lienCity2 = lien.Element("item2").Element("city").Value;                                             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string lienName = lien.Elements().ElementAt(i).Element("name").Value;
```